# Администрирование Mikrotik. Паразитный трафик на 53 порт, что делать?

Tags: администрирование, dns, udp, ddos, mikrotik

На 53/udp порт роутера за сутки падает заметное количество трафика. Уже прочитал про DNS Amplification DDoS.

Сейчас создал правила, которые просто дропают весь трафик по 53 порту. Но, возможно, это неправильное решение.
Посоветуйте, как лучше организовать фильтрацию и необходим ли этот трафик для работы роутера.

UPD: За роутером находится вебсервер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, хочу сказать спасибо за вопрос - он действительно хороший.

Во-вторых, отвечу.

Эта проблема возникает, т.к. включен режим "Allow remote requests".[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Если выключить - Mikrotik перестает работать как DNS сервер. Ситуация в том, что у Вас Mikrotik изначально неправильно настроен. Роутер, смотрящий в интернет, не должен быть "по умолчанию" открыт. Но это больше вопрос не к самому Mikrotik (дефолтная конфигурация там достаточно разумная), а к тому, кто настраивал. Т.е. подытожим:

1. Если DNS не нужен - отключаем эту галку.
2. если файрволл по умолчанию закрыт, то разрешаем все нужные нам сервисы и все хорошо.
3. если файрволл по умолчанию открыт на все, то необходимо закрыть DNS сервис снаружи.

Comment: О, спасибо за резвернутый ответ! нет, ДНС-сервис не нужен.  В дефолтной конфигурации микротик много чего режет, просто открыл вместе с нужными сервисами заодно и ДНС, потом уже узнал о проблеме 53/UDP. В принципе, решение просто дропать в данный момент правильно. Но все-таки красивее,наверно, разрешить входящий трафик на этот порт с доверенных адресов? А  лист доверенных адресов включить корневые днс, их зеркала и днс провайдер.

Comment: Скажем так - DNS в Mikrotik не совсем полноценный. Это вам не BIND все-таки. Например, в Mikrotik можно создавать только A записи. Поэтому его применение - кэширование запросов для внутренних пользователей сети. В остальном, конечно, лучше делать отдельную машину с DNS и прокидывать на нее порты.

Whitelist для файрволла тоже относительно красивое решение. Мы таким образом прикрывали снаружи доступ по SSH, WWW и WinBox для настройки роутера.

Кстати, очень рекомендую отключить MAC Server на WAN интерфейсе...

Comment: Спасибо. Да, мак отключил на внешке